# Why is Laplace transform so useful

Tags: laplace-transform

I recently encountered the term [Laplace transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform).

Since My background is mathematical, the definition itself is very easy for me. The thing which is less clear for me is the context. I assume, that there is a reason why this transform is so important. And this is what I lack off. I can't see why it is important and useful. For instance, suppose that I know that the Laplace transform of a function is converging. So, why is this important. What does it say about the function itself that makes this transform so important?

Thank you!

Comment: If you search the web for "applications of Laplace Transforms" you'll find a pretty large number of pages.

Comment: It might be better to ask "when isn't the Laplace Transform useful?"

Comment: If you'd like more detail, have a look at these delightful MIT lectures on ODEs, starting here (Lecture 19: Introduction to the Laplace Transform): http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-03-differential-equations-spring-2010/video-lectures/lecture-19-introduction-to-the-laplace-transform/

Comment: Thank you all for your help. The lecture is indeed delightful. I also found these: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9BfH-GGgEw8 lectures very helpful! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "classical" use of Laplace transform is in solving linear differential equations (ordinary or partial).  One  reason why it is useful there is that it changes differentiation into multiplication.